# Dell Vostro suddenly giving "No TPM or TPM has..." message on boot

Tags: boot, bios, dell-vostro, tpm

(Original question title was **Dell Vostro suddenly giving "No TPM or TPM has problem" message on boot"** but I was pinged by the stack exchange style police for having the word "problem" in my title!)

I have a Dell Vostro 1510 laptop which spontaneously decided it wouldn't boot.  I get a message

```
No TPM or TPM has problem
```

It was working until then, and nothing in particular was installed/done to it.  TPM was not in use AFAIK.

I have succeeded in booting with a CD recovery Linux disk that has enabled me to mount the internal C:\ drive and copy my stuff to a USB drive, so the stuff is not encrypted.

With a new disk in I still get the message on boot.  Although Linux can see the disk, if I boot with a Windows XP disk, it can't see the new disk so I can't partition it/format it/install XP.

I can't find any option in the BIOS to disable the TPM.

My question is (obviously!):

What can I do?

TIA,
R

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the TPM chip has failed. You can try clearing the cmos by removing the RTC battery for a few minutes, be sure to set date and time in the bios after doing this.

[Source of information](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/p/19350032/19763556.aspx#19763556)